# Gson toJson() method failed generate json string for object class that extends com.mongodb.BasicDBObject

Tags: json, mongodb, gson

I have been having troubles using the Gson.toJson() method to generate a json string that contains the field name and value of all members when my class extends the MongoDB class com.mongodb.BasicDBObject. Here are the codes snippets:

```
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
...
public class TestMongo extends BasicDBObject {
   protected String objectId;
   protected String userId;
   public TestMongo(String oid, String uid) {
     this.objectId = oid;
     this.userId = uid;
   }
   /* getters and setters... */
}
```

Main method test output:

```
TestMongo test = new TestMongo("sample object id","sample user id");
System.out.println((new Gson()).toJson(test));
```

Console output:

{}

Does anyone know if there is a way to get a json string out of my object class which extends the BasicDBObject?

Comment: Try serializing the right variable?

Comment: I apologized... It has been updated now. I must have forgotten to change all variable names when extracting the code snippets...